# SQL Server: How to avoid or detect database restore while application is running

Tags: .net, sql-server, nhibernate, database-restore, hilo

It is required to shut down the system I'm working on before the database gets restored. If a customer does not do this, he may run into serious problems, because the in-memory state of the application server does not match the database. It may take some time until the corrupt database causes errors and the system stops working and the database is unusable.

So I try to detect this situation and avoid the problem.

- **The application server does not necessarily keep a connection alive**, so single user mode and stuff like this most probably wont help.
- I don't care if the restore would fail or the server would shut down or whatever. **It just shouldn't ignore it**.
- the database may be restored by any sql server tool on any machine. I can't rely on my own tools.

Did anyone already solve such a problem?

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and above, .NET (C#), SMO.

---

**Edit:**

Because of some misconceptions and discussions about application design, I need to explain where the problem comes from.

**The Hi-Lo generator**: The application uses NHibernate, which has a cache of Hi-Values of the **Hi-Lo id generator**. The Hi-Values are read from the database and allows the application to generate a specific number of primary keys until it requires to go back to the database and get another range of numbers. The Hi-Values stored in the database are only incremented, but never decremented (unless when a older version of the database is restored). This is the concept of the Hi-Lo generator, it is **neither invented nor implemented by myself**.

**Caches**: In caches, primary keys are used to identify records in the database. Primary keys do never change in normal use of the database. In case of a restore, the primary keys do not identify the same record anymore and the caches are just plain wrong. It **can't even detect this**. It might result, for instance, in setting wrong foreign keys in new records.

A **DB restore can't be compared** to any other normal use of the database. A restore breaks all the rules of data handling.

I guess that many applications keep connections open while they are running, making restore impossible. Most other applications would probably just crash when the database is restored and it tries to access the database afterwards. In my case, it may keep running for awhile, which is a problem.

I guess that most people don't even try to restore the database when the application is running.

There is a theoretical, an in my case proven, risk that something is going completely wrong when a database is restored while the application is still in memory. I don't want to be told that this is not a problem at all, just because most applications do not handle it.

Comment: Can you qualify, what you mean by in memory state please. Are you talking about the SQL Server Buffer Cache, a caching tier, what exactly?

Comment: It's just application memory. Caches, fields in classes etc. It doesn't matter much. One big problem is caused by NHibernates hilo-generator which reserves a range of numbers. These numbers are not valid in another database.

Comment: I think that you need to explain your situation and question more clearly and distinctly.  The responses by myself and others are perfectly valid given your description so far.  In particular, I would like to know how these in-memory cache's are currently protecting themselves from data changes in the database from  sources more mundane than a Restore operation?  How do they know that an Operator, Agent Job, ETL proc, etc. hasn't updated a critical table invalidating the cache and all of its data relations?  If we know that, then we can try to extend it to more obscure cases like Restores.

Comment: @RBarry: There are many values that do not change, and when they do change anyway, they are changed by the server itself. So it caches only such values that are safe to be cached. Main problem, but not the only one: The Hi-Lo generator gets a range of ids by selecting and updating the hi-value in the database. Then it uses these ids, until it runs out of them and requires another range. Applying these ids to another database is corrupting it.

Comment: So you're saying that its only protection against all of those other potential sources of external unmanaged change to the cached data is "that doesn't happen?"  In other words, it has no more protection against them than it does against the Restores.  I'm afraid that what you have here isn't a database problem, it's a seriously flawed SW design issue.  Your Cache Service needs to implement an actual working cache coherency facility based on either proper optimistic or pessimistic concurrency.  Do this and you'll find that the Restore issue will magically disappear as well.

Comment: There are thousands of applications successfully running Hi-Lo generators. There are contracts in databases, like Hi-Values are only incremented. No application is expecting them ever to go down, which would destroy the performance gain of a Hi-Lo generator. Primary keys do never change. If I cache a primary key, I don't expect that it represents a different record when I come back later. Tell me that NH second level caches and other cache implementations expect primary keys to be changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get a useful answer, so I assume that there is no general solution to this problem.

I only see two ways to solve it:

- Executing a query at the begin of every transaction to see if the database is another one. E.g. the last time when it had been restored as [described here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1724/when-was-the-last-time-your-sql-server-database-was-restored/). This may hurt performance and may also be a permissions problem
- I open a "keep-alive" connection to the database which avoids that the database is restored. This may be much easier to implement. It is not very nice, because it wastes a connection.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how you are connecting to the database you could build into your connection logic a check run in a separate state or system database to validate the status of a database.

Maybe do a try / catch around the connection and on a failure check the status and report it back to the user at that point; not sure how often you are restoring so determining the optimum place in your code would require some thought.

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX ('DatabaseName', 'Status')
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186823.aspx

Comment: I don't understand this. What does this check actually check? What status is checked here? The server isn't doing anything while the restore is happening. It gets active after the restore and doesn't recognize that its database had been replaced.

Comment: This will let you trap that a restore is happening; you can then catch that the restore has finished and save your current state? You can't trap via ddl triggers that a restore has been started; though there is an event to handle it. One way to handle this if you are on SQL 2012 is to use sync framework and change tracking via a local DB on the client

Comment: "You can't trap via ddl triggers that a restore has been started" - Sounds like the solution I'm looking for. Can you give me some more details about this? I search for something like this in the documentation but didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do a full restore on a database in SQL Server while there are any connections to it.

And SQL Server will never allow itself to corrupt the in-memory state of the SQL Server.  And you would have to work pretty d**n hard to even trick it into something like that.

Comment: You didn't understand the situation. The server doesn't necessarily keep a connection open while it is running. The corruption is not SQL Servers fault. The application server stores data to the database using information from the previous database, which does not apply to the new database. This is the "in-memory state" problem. The application server doesn't recognize that the whole database had been replaced.